# How to fix packages have unmet dependencies: nodejs : Depends: libnode64?

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I am facing below issue while upgrading in Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
,is there any workaround to fix this issue?

> > You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
> > The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> > nodejs : Depends: libnode64 (= 10.19.0~dfsg-3ubuntu1) but it is not installable
> > Recommends: nodejs-doc
> > E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by an unmet dependency for the nodejs package. The nodejs package depends on the libnode64 package, but that package is not installable. To fix the issue, you can try running `"apt --fix-broken install"` to correct the problem.